# Is there a public CanTopo Web Map Tile Service (WMS / WMTS) available?

Tags: wms, web-mapping, topography, canada, wmts

Does anyone know of a public CanTopo WMS / WMTS available anywhere? I'm assuming CanTopo is more modern / up-to-date than Toporama?

Alternatively, what would be your suggestions for the most pain free and cheapest version to host such a service myself?

The data seems to be freely available here:
http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/data/11042

Comment: Officially it is not available but it is in development "A new national scale Web Map Service (WMS) is being developed and is not currently available." http://atlas.gc.ca/site/english/dataservices/webmapservice.html

Comment: @Mapperz - Thanks for that. Seems the info was last edited 2012-08-30 so I guess I shouldn't hold my breath! :P

Comment: @Gavin, were you able to get anywhere with this? I've been looking around for a good quality BC topographic WMTS to add as a source in my GPS app.

Answer (score 1):

**unofficial** there is a web map that is using the CanVec tiles to create a seamless map of Canada

[image]

copy and paste the link below.

```
 [http://papabearnewyork.com/papabear/BM_Station_GMap.html#width=1024&height=800&title=1&t=topo&z=16&object={station:%22QH0513%22,lat:45.333095544,lng:-71.01308085,designation:%22MARBLE%20IBC%22,status:%22Not%20Found%22,date:%227/12/2006%22,scaled:0,type:%22Survey%20disk%22,agency:%22IBC%22,condition:%22%22}][2]
```

Comment: related is my old blog post http://mapperz.blogspot.ca/2009/09/new-canadian-toporama-wms-service.html

Answer (score 1):

[WMS - Toporama](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/free-data-geogratis/geogratis-web-services/17216#g5) is working again. URL are:

- Toporama WMS English: https://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/toporama_en?request=getcapabilities&service=wms&version=1.3.0
- Toporama WMS French: https://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/toporama_fr?request=getcapabilities&service=wms&version=1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I thought [scruss' answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209340/198469) was correct but those links are dead.

The gov't of Canada website is super confusing but I managed to figure out that the [Canvec](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/8ba2aa2a-7bb9-4448-b4d7-f164409fe056) data is what you're looking for, and they offer a WMS service:

- CanVec WMS English: https://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/canvec_en?request=getcapabilities&service=wms&version=1.3.0&layers=canvec&legend_format=image/png&feature_info_type=text/html
- CanVec WMS French: https://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/canvec_fr?request=getcapabilities&service=wms&version=1.3.0&legend_format=image/png&feature_info_type=text/html&layers=canvec

I'll edit scruss' answer to point to the new toporama links.